# Displaying properties of a class in a listbox from a databound Observable collection WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, observablecollection

I am currently attempting to display items from an `ObservableCollection(myClass)`. The class itself just has some public string properties. I know that the collection is being updated from a stream source correctly but for some reason it's not updating the list box with the properties I want it to. It's very likely that my XAML has some error in it:

```
<Window x:Class="PoSClientWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <ListBox x:Name="pumpListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding PumpCollection}" Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="ID" />
                            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="State" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding pumpID}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                        <TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding state}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

From researching other posts about this very error. I've included adding `this.DataContext = this;` to my `MainWindow` as well as having:

```
public ObservableCollection<PumpItem> PumpCollection
{
    get { return pumpCollection; }
}
```

In order to bind the `ItemsSource` to it. I think there is an error in how I'm declaring the bindings in XAML but I'm not sure. I'm trying to add the properties `pumpID` and `state` to the listbox from the class instance.

The class `pumpItem` is shown below:

```
public enum pumpState
{
    Available,
    customerWaiting,
    Pumping,
    customerPaying
};

public enum fuelSelection
{
    Petrol,
    Diesel,
    LPG,
    Hydrogen,
    None
};

public class PumpItem
{
    public string pumpID;

    public double fuelPumped;
    public double fuelCost;

    public fuelSelection selection;
    public pumpState state;

    public PumpItem(string _ID)
    {
        this.pumpID = _ID;
        this.fuelPumped = 0;
        this.fuelCost = 0;
        this.selection = fuelSelection.None;
        this.state = pumpState.Available;            
    }
}
```

Any pointers or help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind to fields. Change these to public properties

```
public class PumpItem
{
    private string pumpID;
    public string PumpId
    {
        get
        {
             return pumpId;
        }
        set
        {
            pumpId = value;
        }
    }

    private double fuelPumped;
    public double FuelPumped
    {
        get
        {
             return fuelPumped;
        }
        set
        {
            fuelPumped = value;
        }
    }

    private double fuelCost;
    public double FuelCost
    {
        get
        {
             return fuelCost;
        }
        set
        {
            fuelCost= value;
        }
    }

    public fuelSelection selection;
    public fuelSelection Selection
    {
        get
        {
             return selection;
        }
        set
        {
            selection = value;
        }
    }

    public pumpState state;
    public pumpState State
    {
        get
        {
             return state;
        }
        set
        {
            state = value;
        }
    }

    public PumpItem(string _ID)
    {
        this.PumpID = _ID;
        this.FuelPumped = 0;
        this.FuelCost = 0;
        this.Selection = fuelSelection.None;
        this.State = pumpState.Available;
    }
}
```

XAML

```
<TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding PumpID}" Grid.Column="0"/>
<TextBlock Margin="2" Text="{Binding State}" Grid.Column="1"/>
```

Check the Output console for binding errors

Comment: Right on the money with the answer, just a few things like variable name capitalisation. E.g. in your example, it should be private string pumpId; in order to match your variable names. Also the pumpState state; should probably be private. Apart from that, more than happy to mark as answered. Thanks